# fix overscan ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, xrandr, wayland

looks like I can't use xrandr to fix overscan on my monitor now. I used to have a script that set underscan on and set underscan borders. Is there an alternative I can use for 17.10? Thanks!